# Keycloak server is not getting started with cloud DB services

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, wildfly, keycloak

I have a locally hosted Keycloak server which I am able to get up and running with PostgreSQL locally. But when I configure same data source properties to use cloud hosted database service (I am using Compose PostgreSQL : https://www.compose.com/postgresql) it is giving me TimeoutException. 
However Keycloak was able to setup the tables by executing the liquibase properly.

Following are some highlighted error messages in stacktrace.

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
Connection is not associated with a managed connection
IJ000470: You are trying to use a connection factory that has been shut down
```

Following is my standalone.xml file snippet,

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0">
    <datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
            <driver>h2</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>sa</user-name>
                <password>sa</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://<<HOST>>/keycloak_test</connection-url>
            <driver>postgresql</driver>
    <security>
                <user-name></user-name>
                <password></password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
    <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
            <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
        </drivers>
    </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

What am I doing wrong here ?
Following is the stacktrace I am getting.

```
16:36:16,453 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
16:37:39,541 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'add' at address '[
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]'
16:37:41,911 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff7f000001:14dcca52:58de374f:c in state  RUN
16:37:41,913 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffff7f000001:14dcca52:58de374f:c
////
16:37:49,555 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.SecurityRealmAddHandler$ServiceInstallStepHandler@3e01ebb3 for operation {"address" => [("core-service" => "management"),("security-realm" => "ApplicationRealm")],"operation" => "add","map-groups-to-roles" => undefined} at address [
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("security-realm" => "ApplicationRealm")
] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:511)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1369)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1328)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1311)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$300(AbstractOperationContext.java:1185)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:767)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:644)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1344)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:485)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:387)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:349)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:392)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:365)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:299)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

////

16:37:59,560 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$ModelControllerServiceInitializationBootStepHandler$1@d410bc2 for operation {"operation" => "boottime-controller-initializer-step","address" => []} at address [] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
16:37:59,563 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment "keycloak-server.war" was rolled back with no failure message
16:37:59,567 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = mysql
16:37:59,568 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS]
16:37:59,584 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 30) IJ000615: Destroying active connection in pool: KeycloakDS (org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@f71fe24)
16:37:59,584 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 30) IJ000615: Destroying active connection in pool: KeycloakDS (org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@4dc3f1f6)
16:37:59,584 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 30) IJ000615: Destroying active connection in pool: KeycloakDS (org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@1e5b70f1)
16:37:59,590 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.TypeInfo] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HHH000362: Unable to retrieve type info result set : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
16:37:59,601 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.TypeInfo] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HHH000362: Unable to retrieve type info result set : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
16:37:59,604 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
16:37:59,606 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@116aebf3
16:37:59,616 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) Envers integration enabled? : true
16:37:59,865 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = postgresql
16:38:00,441 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.3.Final
16:38:01,742 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
16:38:03,344 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
16:38:03,344 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000470: You are trying to use a connection factory that has been shut down: java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
16:38:03,346 INFO  [org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
16:38:03,347 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) ARJUNA012077: Abort called on already aborted atomic action 0:ffff7f000001:14dcca52:58de374f:d
16:38:03,351 ERROR [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.CustomLockService] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) Database error during release lock: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk7.WrappedConnectionJDK7@2b57311c
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.commit(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1130)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.CustomLockService.releaseLock(CustomLockService.java:184)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lambda$releaseLock$1(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:126)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:544)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.releaseLock(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:123)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:140)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:228)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    ////
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk7.WrappedConnectionJDK7@2b57311c
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.commit(JdbcConnection.java:126)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.commit(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1128)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk7.WrappedConnectionJDK7@2b57311c
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.lock(WrappedConnection.java:164)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.getAutoCommit(WrappedConnection.java:802)
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.commit(JdbcConnection.java:122)
    ... 32 more

16:38:03,352 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) ARJUNA012077: Abort called on already aborted atomic action 0:ffff7f000001:14dcca52:58de374f:c
16:38:03,357 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./auth: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./auth: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:162)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2209)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:299)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:240)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:113)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:231)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.keycloak.models.ModelException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.PersistenceExceptionConverter.convert(PersistenceExceptionConverter.java:61)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.PersistenceExceptionConverter.invoke(PersistenceExceptionConverter.java:51)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.find(Unknown Source)
    at org.keycloak.models.jpa.MigrationModelAdapter.getStoredVersion(MigrationModelAdapter.java:38)
    at org.keycloak.migration.MigrationModelManager.migrate(MigrationModelManager.java:68)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateModel(KeycloakApplication.java:238)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateAndBootstrap(KeycloakApplication.java:179)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:138)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:228)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:150)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1619)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1106)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1033)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.PersistenceExceptionConverter.invoke(PersistenceExceptionConverter.java:49)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3956)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2600(SessionImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2696)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:975)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1075)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000470: You are trying to use a connection factory that has been shut down: java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:146)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000470: You are trying to use a connection factory that has been shut down: java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:735)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
    ... 64 more

16:38:03,377 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested.
```

Comment: Did you find some workaround ?

Comment: Some news about this?

Comment: Sorry, I could not find any...

Answer (score 0):

For `coordinator-environment` add a `default-timeout` in seconds, e.g. 36000 seconds for 10 minutes. You will need to adjust it according to your system, so you may need to set it much higher. That solved this issue for me (ARJUNA012117), but with MySQL on the initial setup of Keycloak 14.

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:6.0">
  ...
  <coordinator-environment default-timeout="36000" .../>
  ...
</subsystem>
```